# Gallery for IPhone UI controls

Tags: iphone, user-interface

Is there any web-resource (gallery perhaps) showing all user interface elements made from UIView(or other?), so it will give me some quick idea what controls exist, what do they look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a web resource per se (depending on what you mean), but you can get the [source code for the UICatalog sample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple and see what is offered. It's also a good project to look at in case you want to go beyond the look and and actually see how it's implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but [here](http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/iphone/)'s a PSD file containing all the iPhone UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Omnigraffle, there is an iPhone stencil. http://graffletopia.com/stencils/392